# What is the best way to authorize the user in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to authorization the user in angular 5. Currently I am saving the user ID and user email in local storage and before sending any request or redirecting to some page I usually check the if the user ID and user email is present in the local storage or not and while sending the request in API side I checks if user is valid or not, but I want to do this angular as I don't want user to wait until the user is authorized or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saving directly username or password in storage, You can implement TOKEN BASED AUTHENTICATION here.
Save that token in local storage and use that for re-login.

You can take guidelines from link :

http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2016/11/easy-angular-authentication-with-json.html

Comment: What is If I want to encode and decode the token in angular side not in the API.And I am using the Angular 5

Comment: You can use Javascript base64 encryption here. You can find it on Google easily.